# How can we do 301 and 302 redirection with angular and node? Angular app is working as server side rendering app ( angular universal)

Tags: angular, redirect, http-status-code-301, angular-universal, http-status-code-302

I am working on a CMS system with angular as a front-end and .net mvc as a backend for my api's. Angular universal with server side rendering is also implemented.

The issue is i cannot figure out how to redirect with 301 and 302. My application has a dynamic blog section and if let's say /abc blog is clicked, i want to redirect it to /xyz with 301 or 302. I have searched a lot but have not found solution. I can navigate from front-end by router.navigate() but how can i perform redirection?

Comment: You need to inject the response object from the nodejs server. Are you using express engine?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this.